# In-app purchase product stuck in Waiting for Upload status

Tags: ios, flutter, in-app-purchase

I have an app that is fully developed and released to the store with several updates, and has 3 products: `product_a`, `product_b` and `product_c` created on the store.
Initial app build had `product_a` only, and I was able to submit the product with the initial build and I got it approved. Problem now is that I added 2 more products, but they are stuck in Waiting for Upload status, and I can't attach them to this release. How is that possible? What am I missing? All the fields in IAP product are filled, so there is no data missing (cleared for sale is selected, content hosting is set to host on Apple, review text and screenshot is present). Product type is non-consumable.

Answer (score 0):

Is that product_a, product_b and product_c are different apps? if its different apps you need to create another folder in the same account.

Comment: product_a, product_b and product_c are 3 in-app purchase products within a single application.